# Get "And" operation on a field in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have table1 that have a "status" field of type bit

[image]

i wanna get true if all rows have status=1(true)

how to do this?

Comment: Specify your sample data and expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the help of @Vicky_Thinking's answer i wrote this:

```
select isnull((SELECT top 1 status FROM Table1 WHERE status <> 1),1)
```

result is 1 if all rows have status=1 and otherwise result is 0

Answer (score 4):

If I get your question correctly, this can help you. You want true if all rows have status equal to 1.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table1 WHERE status <> 1)
   SELECT 'false'
ELSE
   SELECT 'true'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    select case when SUM(case when status=1 then 1 ELSE 0 end) =  COUNT(*) then 'true' 
                else 'false' end
    from tab
```

Comment: it worked too,thank you,but @Vicky_Thinking answer is more readable and easier to understand

Comment: @Ali7091 But I feel this is a better solution. +1